# How do I avoid an "N+1 Select" and specify fetch strategy for (N)Hibernate user type which has many-to-one?

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a composite component which has a many-to-one reference.

```
class MyComposite
{
    SomeEntity ManyToOne { get; set; }
    SomeOtherUserType Value { get; set; }
}
```

For ease of mapping, I've made a custom `ICompositeUserType` which encompases this component:

```
class MyCompositeUserType : ICompositeUserType
{
    // ...
    private static readonly IType[] _propertyTypes = new[]
                                   {
                                       new ManyToOneType("SomeEntity"), 
                                       new CustomType(typeof(SomeOtherUserType))
                                   };
    // ...
}
```

Now, I have a collection of `composite-element`s which include this component:

```
<class name="Container">
...
<set name="Pairings"
     cascade="all-delete-orphan"
     generic="true"
     lazy="false"
     table="Pairings"
     fetch="join">
    <key column="ContainerId" />
    <composite-element class="Pair">
        <property name="Item1" type="mycomposite" lazy="false">
            <column name="Entity1Id" />
            <column name="Amount1" />
        </property>
        <property name="Item2" type="mycomposite" lazy="false">
            <column name="Entity2Id" />
            <column name="Amount2" />
        </property>
        <property name="Tag" column="Tag" />
    </composite-element>
</set>
</class>
```

When I query on the `Container` class, the `Pairings` set is loaded eagerly, as designed, however, I then get an *N+1* select on the `SomeEntity` which forms a part of the `MyCompositeUserType`. I want to load those entities along with the join on the `Pairings` set.

How can this be specified?

Comment: What code are you using to query? Are you specifing a Fetch to load the related entities? if so are you then using a transformer to remove the duplicate root elements?

Comment: No extra fetches on the query. It's just a stright ToList.

Comment: is there a reason you need `ICompositeUserType` instead of `<component>` mapping?

Comment: Yes, it makes mapping the many instances in which it is used easier and the resulting mapping document more succinct.

Comment: @Firo - are you saying that not mapping with a user type gives me the option to specify the fetch type?

Answer (score 0):

if mapped as component you can map it as many to one with lazy="false" or it should be possible to set the fetchmode when querying

```
<composite-element class="Pair">
    <component name="Item1">
        <many-to-one name="Entity1" column="Entity1Id" />
        <property name="Amount" column="Amount1" />
    </component>
    <component name="Item2">
        <many-to-one name="Entity2" column="Entity2Id"/>
        <property name="Amount" column="Amount2" />
    </component>
    <property name="Tag" column="Tag" />
</composite-element>
```